# Is it possible to get list of in-app purchases from Google Play API directly to my server?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I need to integrate google play in-app purchases with my server-side billing.

Any way to get list of in-app purchases via some Google Play API to my server without client app in between?

Tried to find anything relevant in documentation and all I found is [status check API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html) which gives you status of specific purchase, but I need to get list of purchases too.

Comment: can you check this link http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases

Comment: this is to use in Android while user is logged in, but I need to make a call from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's possible via Callback functions in Integration tab of Settings page but only if you have classic Google Checkout account.

If you just registered as Android Developer — you have a different type of account and those options are unavailable for you.

No way to sign up for classic account as Google Checkout is being substituted by Google Wallet and no way to change account time once you are registered.

sarcasm on:Thank you, Google!:sarcasm off